# Visualizing the Model using export_graphviz from .pkl file

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have exported the model into `.pkl` file. Now I am trying to import via `Joblib` which imports in form `sklearn.model_selection._search.GridSearchCV`.

However I am not able to use from `sklearn.tree` import `export_graphvizexport_graphviz` as it expects `tree_` as the first parameter.

Is there any way to do this? Here is my code:

> export_graphviz(model,out_file="out.dot")
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/tree/export.py", line 433, in export_graphviz
>       recurse(decision_tree.tree_, 0, criterion=decision_tree.criterion)
>   AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'tree_'

Answer (score -1):

How did you define the gridSearchCV and train it?

Most probably the underlying tree in the gridSearchCV can be accessed by:-

```
decision_tree.best_estimator_.tree_
```

if `decision_tree` is a gridsearchcv object